# PHP Regular Expression to match `name[50]` to the "name" and "50" values

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm looking for some more regular expression help, to work with the PHP function `preg_match`. I need to match the following strings;

- `string[50]`
- `string`

Ideally the array returned would be something like this;

- `string`, `50`
- `string`

Any help would be appreciated :-)
This was what I came up with but it doesn't remotely do what I expected with my little regex knowledge! `/([a-z])+(\[[0-9]\])?/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `+` within the `()` (otherwise you'll match the full string only the last character of the string will be in the result group). Also add another `+` after `[0-9]`. Move the `\[\]` outside the `()` to return only `50` (not `[50]`) and use `(?:)?` to make the `[50]` optional without yielding a group.

```
/([a-z]+)(?:\[([0-9]+)\])?/i
```

[Play with it on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9f52N5VBHi)

Comment: YAY! Thanks. How could I get it to match without the [] around it? :)

Comment: @tarnfeld That's also going to match `string50`, which I'm not sure you meant. See my edit which might be a better solution for you.

Comment: Your edit made it so much better + nice explanation. Thank you!!